# how to add string into other String in specific location

Tags: java, android, string

how to insert String in other string
in Android ,I can use getString(R.string.xxx,"insert term")

but in java, how could I do it?

```
public class const() {
    public static String rawWording = "here is % Text"

    public void main() {
        String text = "java";
        String result = (const.rawWording, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: try: String.format("The original %s is tested", "text");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String.format like

```
String output = String.format("%s doe", "John");
```

For more information and ways, you can refer [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples)

Comment: linking to another site is not an acceptable answer. at best, may be posted as comment

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, My intention is that the respective user should study all the ways we can used String.format method for his better understanding. Just providing answer to his problem is not a good approach (My Opinion).

Your thoughts are welcome too.

Comment: Please see: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)
[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370). In short, answers should always be able to stay on their own, even if linked resource will disappear. Links are great as *additional* resource, but they can't be *only/main* content of an answer.

Comment: Thanks Pshemo & Sharon. I'll consider you points. :)...

Updated my answer.